# Как заменить повторяющихся индексы на новые?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, оптимизация, матрицы

У меня есть двумерный массив, в котором в первом столбце должны быть написаны уникальные числа от 1 до n. Проблема в том, что некоторых чисел там несколько и нужно заменить повторяющиеся на максимальное + 1.

database - название массива, который нужно обработать.

Вот так я пробовал, но тут происходит замена всех повторяющихся чисел, а мне нужно оставить уникальное число напротив каждого рядка:

```
array2 = np.unique(database[:, 0], return_counts=True)
        i = 0
        max = np.amax(array2[0]) + 1
        while array2[1].size > i:
            if(array2[1][i] > 1):
                database[database == array2[0][i]] = max
                max = max + 1
            i = i + 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я доделал и оно работает, но я думаю, что это можно сделать в несколько строк, а не писать вот такие циклы

```
            array2 = np.unique(database[:, 0], return_counts=True)
        i = 0
        max = np.amax(array2[0]) + 1
        while array2[1].size > i:
            if(array2[1][i] > 1):
                q = np.where(database[ : , 0] == array2[0][i])
                j = 1
                while j < q[0].size:
                    database[q[0][j]][0] = max
                    max = max + 1
                    j = j + 1
            i = i + 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы хотите заменить дубликаты: `[5,6,6,6,7,8,8]` -> `[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` или так: `[5,6,6,6,7,8,8]` -> `[5,6,max+1,max+2,max+3,7,max+4]` ?

Comment: На второй вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = database[:, 0]
idx = np.arange(1, len(a))[np.diff(a) == 0]
a[idx] = np.arange(a.max() + 1, a.max() + len(idx) + 1)
```

Пример:

исходный вектор:

```
In [101]: a = np.array([5,6,6,6,7,8,8,9])

In [102]: a
Out[102]: array([5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9])
```

решение:

```
idx = np.arange(1, len(a))[np.diff(a) == 0]

a[idx] = np.arange(a.max() + 1, a.max() + len(idx) + 1)
```

результат:

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: array([ 5,  6, 10, 11,  7,  8, 12,  9])
```

Comment: Может знаете в чем проблема:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cibermag/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py", line 165, in <module>
    idx = np.arange(1, len(database))[np.diff(database) == 0]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: @AlexanderMoroz, сделайте сначала: `a = database[:, 0]`, а потом попробуйте мое решение

Comment: Работает, бомба!
Спасибо!